# transpose from one variable under another in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

here example of my data

```
 mydat=structure(list(ADR.N.14.0 = c(8140010250001, 8140010250002), 
    NOMYAR.N.16.6 = c(1, 1), KOFPOR1.N.16.6 = c(7, 10), POR1.C.254 = c("о", 
    "BB"), VOZPOR1.N.16.6 = c(80, 45), VYSPOR1.N.16.6 = c(24, 
    17), DEMPOR1.N.16.6 = c(36, 16), POLNOT1.N.16.6 = c(0.6, 
    0.9), ZAPZAH1.N.16.6 = c(210, 160), NOMYAR2.N.16.6 = c(1, 
    1), KOFSOCT2.N.16.6 = c(3, 0), POR2.C.254 = c("BB", "о"), 
    VOZPOR2.N.16.6 = c(70, 45), VYSPOR2.N.16.6 = c(22, 17), DEMPOR2.N.16.6 = c(26, 
    22), POLNOT2.N.16.6 = c(0, 0), ZAPZAH2.N.16.6 = c(0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

how for each value of `ADR,N,14,0`move data from one variable under another.
To be more clear
here variables with prefix1

```
NOMYAR,N,16,6   KOFPOR**1**,N,16,6  POR**1**,C,254  VOZPOR**1**,N,16,6  VYSPOR**1**,N,16,6  DEMPOR**1**,N,16,6  POLNOT**1**,N,16,6  ZAPZAH**1**,N,16,6
```

and near rows with prefix2

```
NOMYAR**2**,N,16,6  KOFPOR**2**,N,16,6  POR**2**,C,254  VOZPOR**2**,N,16,6  VYSPOR**1**,N,16,6  DEMPOR**2**,N,16,6  POLNOT**2**,N,16,6  ZAPZAH**2**,N,16,6
```

so i need that for  for A`DR,N,14,0` =8140010250001
the content of the fields with the prefix 2 was under the content of the fields with the prefix 1
like this

```
result=structure(list(ADR.N.14.0 = c(8140010250001, 8140010250001, 8140010250002, 
8140010250002, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), NOMYAR.N.16.6 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), KOFPOR1.N.16.6 = c(7, 3, 10, 
0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), POR1.C.254 = c("о", "BB", "BB", "о", 
"", "", "", "", "", ""), VOZPOR1.N.16.6 = c(80, 70, 45, 45, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), VYSPOR1.N.16.6 = c(24, 22, 17, 17, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), DEMPOR1.N.16.6 = c(36, 26, 16, 22, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), POLNOT1.N.16.6 = c(0.6, 0, 0.9, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), ZAPZAH1.N.16.6 = c(210, 0, 160, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

How can i do such transpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pivot_longer` and specify `names_pattern` to include pattern of names that you want together.

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(mydat, cols = -ADR.N.14.0, 
                    names_to = c('.value'), 
                    names_pattern = '(.*?)\\d?\\..*')

#     ADR.N.14.0 NOMYAR KOFPOR POR   VOZPOR VYSPOR DEMPOR POLNOT ZAPZAH KOFSOCT
#          <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 8140010250001      1      7 о         80     24     36    0.6    210       3
#2 8140010250001      1     NA BB        70     22     26    0        0      NA
#3 8140010250002      1     10 BB        45     17     16    0.9    160       0
#4 8140010250002      1     NA о         45     17     22    0        0      NA
```